# What counts as a day for water purifiers?

Tags: fallout-4

The game states that any excess purified water from your purifiers will go into your workshop every day.

What counts as a day? I tried sleeping in a bed for 24h but that didn't trigger water to be deposited into my workshop. Nor did it give my traders back their caps.

So what counts? Time spent away from the settlement?

Comment: Can you check out [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/247199/3107) and see if that resolves your issue with no purified water being generated?

Comment: This seems to be pretty much the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your amazing write up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Summary

**I was able to get things to regenerate via a combination of sleeping for 24 hours and then idling in game for a few minutes.**

That being said, there are other reasons why your purified water may not be showing up. I've had an issue where, for weeks, Sanctuary wasn't storing extra water even though it should have been. **There appears to be a bug (or undocumented feature) related to inventory in the *Aid* section of a settlement's workshop. Removing *dirty water* and *purified water* from your workshop appears to allow another batch of *purified water* to spawn.**

#### Backstory

I have been experience this issue for weeks now in Sanctuary. When I took over The Castle, I temporarily had purified water being sent to my workshop, but it stopped after a while as well. Both settlements produce over 100 water and have sufficient food, defenses, power, and settlers to keep things running. The machines are powered and active.

After reading through a fair amount of misinformation (you don't need empty bottles in your workshop) and bad assumptions on the Steam forums (see links below), I came across [one theory](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136918058836/#c492379439678277366) that held some merit: People claimed moving some aid items from their workshop was addressing the issue. Some claimed you just had to move *dirty water* and *purified water*, others claimed you had to remove everything.

#### My Experiment

To be safe, I built an ice cooler in The Castle and moved everything from the *Aid* section of both workshops to it. Then, I slept for 24 hours. Both workshops were still empty. I left my console running for a few minutes while I went to do something else. When I came back, the water (and crops!) I was over-producing were finally appearing in the workshops of both settlements.

#### Additional Considerations

Initially, I removed everything in the *Aid* section of my workshop just to be safe, and *purified water* started spawning again. I've since re-added everything but *dirty water*, *purified water*, rare chems, and cooked food to the workshop and I am still getting purified water. I think the issue is related specifically to having water already in your workshop, but I have not verified that rare chems or cooked food might also have an impact.

It doesn't appear to be related to anything your settlement overproduces. The Castle generates more crops than I use, but not clearing out the excess crops hasn't prevented the *purified water* from spawning.

References:

- [Settlement (Sanctuary) not generating purified water](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492378265882631667/)
- [The Secret to Producing useable Water](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136918058836/)

Comment: I've been consistently generating purified water just by keeping my workshop clear of purified water. You can have other stuff in the Aid section.

Comment: @DCShannon Clearing *purified water* was not enough in my case. I believe you when you say you can have *some* stuff in the Aid section, but you definitely have to clear more than just you *purified water* to get your settlement to store another batch.

Comment: You might have to clear the dirty water as well, I've seen that mentioned, and I rarely have any in my workshop. There's a long list of extra chems, meats, roasts, and crops in there pretty much all the time though.

Comment: @DCShannon Possibly. My other theory is that you have to clear out anything your settlement is over-producing. So, if you generate more corn than you consume and your settlement would otherwise try to store more corn in your workshop, you need to clear corn out as well. I haven't tested this yet, however.

Comment: That's also possible. Whatever it is, I think it's clear that it's some kind of bug. I was testing whether crops would show up if you already had crops in yesterday, but couldn't make much sense of the results. I left a few of each crop I was growing in my workshop, then went about my business and came back the next day. There was more corn, the same tatos (I've never had tatos be auto-harvested), and *less* mutfruit. The water was gathered just fine, independently of those crops.

Comment: @DCShannon I noticed something similar. Sanctuary produced a little of everything, but The Castle only had more corn (even though I'm making corn, tatos, and mutifruit for adhesives). I think it's because I'm making 18 food for 15 settlers, so only 3 food is hitting my workshop, and the game arbitrarily chose 3 corn as the food store. In Sanctuary, I'm making 18 food for 9 people, and I think I ended up with 9 food units in the workshop (split across a few crop types).

Comment: Also, if you have supply lines, isn't excess water/food taken to other settlements?

Answer (score 3):

I have just tested this for you - I have an industrial water purifier and 20 settlers in my settlement, this means I have 20 units of water left at the end of each day. I took all of the water out of my store and then slept for 24 hours and woke up to 20 purified water in my store.

Since there are many systems in the game (such as dynamic time of day, NPCs only available at certain times, shops only opening at certain times etc) the game is well aware of what "time" it is - have you considered that maybe you have no excess purified water? That purified water only comes from the powered pumps and that each settler uses 1 unit of water?

Comment: I have 4 industrial water purifiers and I didn't notice an increase in my supply. I have 17 settlers so I should be getting plenty.

Comment: Perhaps I messed up I will test it again shortly

Comment: @InvkrMainr Are all the purifiers powered and on? Kalina tested an industrial purifier. Are yours regular purifiers, or industrial ones?

Comment: I tested this with a regular water purifier in a settlement with no settlers, and I get 10 waters a day.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem I:

1. Removed the hand pumps that I had place early in my settlement. They were enough to cover the needs of my settlers so perhaps the industrial purifiers were not being "used" despire being powered and on.
2. Pulled up and stored my purifiers and replaced them.

I slept 24 hours and this seemed to fix the issue.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is your extra water being moved by supply lines? Those places that don't have enough water are getting water through your supply lines. So it make sense that the extra water at one settlement is being transferred to those that does not have enough water.

Comment: This won't result in the bottles of water being put in the other workshop, but should result in a reduction in the "excess" water, and therefore the amount of bottles produced.

Answer (score 0):

Some have said that you actually need to be "doing stuff" for the water purifiers to do their thing, so sleeping will not work.

I have a load of them set up at Sanctuary, I go away and explore for an hour and come back to find over 200 lots of purified water to sell.

So if sleeping isn't working for you, simply leave Sanctuary and do stuff for a while, then when you get back it should be waiting at the workshop for you.